# How to prevent renderHeaderCell() call when column reorder is done by the user

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I have a Dojo extentions dgrid with the following declaration :

```
var myGridTemplate = declare([ OnDemandGrid,ColumnReorder,Keyboard,Selection,selector,Pagination,ColumnResiser]);

var myGrid = new myGridTemplate(
                {
                    deselectOnRefresh : true,
                    cellNavigation : true,
                    loadingMessage : "Loading data...",
                    noDataMessage : "No data found.",

                columns : {

                    xyz : {
                            label : Mylabel,
                            width : 50,
                            renderHeaderCell: function(col_node) {
                                col_field = "xyz";
                                this_filter_col = this;
                                  domConstruct.create("div", {
                                      innerHTML: this_filter_col.label,
                                      intermediateChanges: true
                                  }, col_node);

                                .
                                var form = new Form({style: "font-size: 11px"});
                                .
                                var tc = new TabContainer({
                                style: "height: 220px; width: 300px;",
                                        useMenu    : false,
                                        useSlider  : false,
                                        tabStrip   : false,
                                         tabPosition: "top",
                                         doLayout   : true
                                 });
                                    tc.placeAt(form.domNode);

                                    var cp = new ContentPane({
                                        region: "top",
                                style: "padding: 5px; border-bottom: none;" });
                                .
                                .

                                }
                        .
                        .
                        });
```

In the above code `Renderheadcell()` method adds a filtering form to each header ( Above example "xyz") which pops up when I click on a button present in the header.
Everything works fine, But when I do column re-order the form(having widgets like textbox,radio button, etc) which are present in `renderHeaderCell()` block are getting reset automatically and drawn again.
Because of which I am unable to retain the values in the form which are required to show what filters I have applied on a particular column.

How to prevent `renderHeaderCell()` call when column-reorder is done by the user ?

Any solution/pointers will greatly help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When columns are reordered, dgrid updates the structure of the grid which results in `renderHeader` being re-called, which in turn results in `renderHeaderCell` being re-called as well.

You will need to internally maintain the state of your widgets and restore them yourself.  If you're using Dijit input widgets then you might want to consider using `dijit/form/Form` instead of directly using an HTML form element, since you can then watch `value` for changes and update state information accordingly.

I would also, however, suggest that you maintain references to whatever widgets you are creating in your header cells, and extend `_destroyColumns` to make sure any widgets you created are properly destroyed before the header is re-rendered.

Comment: Thanks Ken. Please suggest any scalable method to save and restore form values for each dgrid columns. Because we have a quite a number of grids in our application for which I need to maintain the save filter information (Form values).